# Django admin misbehaves after adding for django.contrib.sites on server

Tags: django, django-admin, django-allauth, django-sites

Django Admin Site was working fine on local server.
But the same thing when deployed on server. Admin CSS misbehaves See Screenshot [Admin panel screenshot on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeIPZ.png)

admin panel site also working fine on mobile responsive view or small screens

On localhost it looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWj0W.png).

I have ran collect static several times on server but nothing happens.
Tried Clearing Cache many time.
Nothing worked
But localhost seems to work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer myself.
Initially a old version of site already working on server.
Then i added django.contrib.sites for django.contrib.sites

Upon adding that when update is pushed to server then

> python manage.py collectstatic

command does not completely replace old files.And It doesn't work well with old files.

- So run collectstatic command on local
- upload generated folder to
  server to avoid any such issues